# How to split the loop every 2 and 5 results?

Tags: loop, split

im trying to display my WP loop with this layout:

```
(POST 1) (POST 2)/
(POST 3) (POST 4) (POST 5)/
(POST 6) (POST 7)/
(POST 8) (POST 9) (POST 10)
```

and so goes on. Any ideas?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that using $wp_query->current_post inside the loop. It returns the current posts index number inside the loop (starting form 0). Have a look at the following code block

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
while(have_posts()){
    the_post();
    the_title();
    //do your other stuff

    if($wp_query->current_post==1){
        //do what you want to do after 2nd post
    }else if($wp_query->current_post==5){
        //do what you want to do after 6th post
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this snippet will work only for the first 5 results, correct? I'm trying to achieve this result on the entire loop.

Comment: Great answer. Just a note, if you are inside the main loop of the main query, you don't need (or have to) to declare the `$wp_query` global. It is available by default. So are a global like `$post`. But again, go with personal choice :-)

Comment: @Night use the modulo operator `%` to find multiples of a number

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a friend, i got the solution:

```
<?php
        $line = 1;
        $col = 1;
        while(have_posts()) : the_post();
        if ($line % 2 == 0) {
            $class = 'grid_2'; // class for the 3 smaller posts
        } else {
            $class = 'grid_3'; // class for the 2 bigger posts
        }
    ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        if (($col == 2 ) || ($col == 5 )) {
            $line++;
            if ($col == 5) {
                $col = 0;
            }
        }
        $col++;
        endwhile;
    ?>
```